# How to display Dynamic added switch button values in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need help for vue js. I have added dynamically switch button then get all values from array when i change the each switch

```js
mounted(){

 this.disclamer_status =this.liveProgramProductForm.getFieldDecorator('disclamer_status['+ element.id +']', { valuePropName: 'checked',initialValue: element.disclaim_status,preserve: true });     

}
```

Comment: Can you create a codepen for the above issue, that would be really helpful to solve your issue faster..

Comment: kindly create an example in jsfiddle or codepen so it will be easier to understand and answer

Comment: Hi Friend's ,  how to add dynamically class in ant with vuejs . for if switch button active in form edit page.

Comment: if(element.disclaim_status ==1)
            {
              this.check=true;
            }else if(element.disclaim_status ==0){
              this.check=false;
            }
           this.disclamer_status =this.liveProgramProductForm.getFieldDecorator('disclamer_status['+ element.id +']', {initialValue: this.check,preserve: true });